# AsyncHttpClient OnSuccess is not executed

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

This is what I get in the console:

```
onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received
```

I verified and the file is uploaded to the server.

This is my code and the app doesn't complain :

```
public void uploadImage() {
        //Create a new RequestParams that will send paremeters with our AsyncHttpClient request.
        RequestParams data = new RequestParams();

        //Adding our image to the parameters.
        File image = new File(imgPath);
        try {
        data.put("image", image);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
    //Create a new AsyncHttpClient request.
    //here we're sending a POST request, the first parameter is the request URL
    // then our RequestParams, in our case data and then a Json response handler.
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(FILE_UPLOAD_URL, data, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header headers[], JSONArray success) {
            try {
                JSONObject data = success.getJSONObject(0);
                String m = data.getString("message");
                Toast.makeText(UploadPhotoTest.this, m, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is what I'm importing if it's relevant :

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

My problem is that whatever is in OnSuccess never gets executed .. I put a log in the OnSuccess try and catch and nothing gets printed. How can I solve this ?

Comment: AsyncHttpClient has multiple onSuccess methods. I guess the server does not return JSONArray after file is uploaded. You can check other onSuccess methods in the library and override them.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll look into that. I think it is returning a JSONArray because before using this library I was using something else that was working, but I saw on the internet that this is the best library to use if you upload or receive a lot of data.

Comment: @kasto_manche where could I find those methods ?

Comment: Obviously in the AynchHttpClient library documentation. Since your response handler class is JsonHttpResponseHandler, the url is [link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html)

Comment: @Daniel, from the response in the console , you should replace JSONArray with JSONObject in onSuccess method.

Comment: Very recent version of AsyncHTTPClient has only this callback for success: `@Override
            public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                try {
                    String content = new String(arg2, StrEncode);
                    System.out.println(content);
                    CONSTANTS.FinishedProgress();
                    ParseAllDataClass.ParseLoginData(content, c);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }`

Answer (score 1):

`public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {`

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject in all places, you are getting response "Success" in JSONArray.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).